# Examine raw HTTP request from UrlFetchApp.fetch

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on something to interact with Amazon's REST API, but I keep getting an error in my response that points to a mal-formed request. I don't see any errors in the code (the parameter that it says is missing is clearly there), so I want to see the raw request that is being sent.

I don't see any available method that will let me do this. Maybe a server that will just include my request as its response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own endpoint that will echo to the screen your request. For example, to echo a GET request, send it to a script like this (that's been Publish > Deploy as web app):

```
function doGet(e) {
  var test = 'Echo at ' + new Date() + '\n' + e.queryString;
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(test);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the game (10 years) but you can now do this:

```
const requestResult = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, options);
```

Run it in debug mode and break after this executes to examine `requestResult`.

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#getrequesturl,-params for an official description and a full explanation of the properties for the `options` parameter.